# lines to columns with awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk, columns, xml

I have to following sample output:

```
<HARDWARE>
    <NAME>WIN1</NAME>
    <OS>Windows 7</OS>
    <IP>1.2.3.4</IP>
    <DOMAIN>contoso.com</DOMAIN>
</HARDWARE>
<HARDWARE>
    <NAME>WIN2</NAME>
    <OS>Windows 8</OS>
    <IP>10.20.30.40</IP>
    <DOMAIN>contoso.com</DOMAIN>
</HARDWARE>
```

What is the best way to parse it so it will look like:

```
WIN1    Windows 7    1.2.3.4     contoso.com
WIN2    Windows 8    10.20.30.40 contoso.com
```

Looking for a solution to use standard tools like awk, sed etc

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet, ...).

Comment: Is that exactly your output? Because that's not valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use `awk` `sed` etc. They cannot handle `XML` properly. `XML` does a bunch of stuff like having whitespace, linefeeds, unary tags etc. that means regular expressions aren't very robust - they break messily, following a *perfectly valid* change to XML down the line.

The way to handle `XML` is with a parser. `xmlstarlet` is one commonly used on Linux. Because I haven't seen it suggested yet- I'd use perl. E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ('your_xml_file.xml'); 
foreach my $HW ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//HARDWARE' ) ) {
    print join ( "\t", map { $_ -> text } $HW -> children ),"\n";
}
```

- Parse the XML
- iterate the `HARDWARE` elements.
- Extract the `text` from the children
- print that.

You could extend it a little to allow you to handle e.g. different field sets/ordering:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @fields_to_show = qw ( OS NAME ); 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'your_filename.xml' ); 
foreach my $HW ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//HARDWARE' ) ) {
    my %fields =  map { $_ -> tag => $_ -> text } $HW -> children;
    print join ("\t", @fields{@fields_to_show}),"\n"; 
}
```

It generates a hash (associative array) called `%fields` that looks like (for each element):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'OS' => 'Windows 7',
          'NAME' => 'WIN1',
          'DOMAIN' => 'contoso.com',
          'IP' => '1.2.3.4'
        };
```

And then we use `@fields_to_show` to specify which to display and in which order.

So this will thus print:

```
Windows 7   WIN1
Windows 8   WIN2
```

NB: I also has to 'fix' your XML, because without a single root tag it's invalid. Other answers have mentioned this. The `XML` spec is quite strict - broken `XML` should be rejected. So it's actually quite bad form to "fix" XML and normally I'd suggest hitting whoever generated it around the head with a copy of the XML spec.

Answer (score 7):

With a slight modification to your XML, wrap all your XML in a parent `<DATA>` tag<sup>1</sup>, or another one of your choosing, file called `data.xml`:

```
<DATA>
<HARDWARE>
    <NAME>WIN1</NAME>
    <OS>Windows 7</OS>
    <IP>1.2.3.4</IP>
    <DOMAIN>contoso.com</DOMAIN>
</HARDWARE>
<HARDWARE>
    <NAME>WIN2</NAME>
    <OS>Windows 8</OS>
    <IP>10.20.30.40</IP>
    <DOMAIN>contoso.com</DOMAIN>
</HARDWARE>
</DATA>
```

Using `xmlstarlet` + `column`

```
 xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /DATA/HARDWARE -v "concat(NAME,' ',OS,' ',IP,' ',DOMAIN)" -n data.xml | column -t
```

gives:

```
WIN1  Windows  7  1.2.3.4      contoso.com
WIN2  Windows  8  10.20.30.40  contoso.com
```

**Edit:**

Based on Peter.O's great catch in the comments and his [answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225733/4252), let's send pipe delimited<sup>2</sup> output to `column -ts$'|'`, so something like:

```
xmlstarlet sel --indent-tab -T -t -m /DATA/HARDWARE -v "concat(NAME,'|',OS,'|',IP,'|',DOMAIN)" -n data.xml | column -ts$'|'
```

Now, the fields line up nicely even if they have spaces:

```
WIN1              Windows 7  1.2.3.4 release 5  contoso.com
Really long OS X  Windows 8  10.20.30.40        contoso.com
```

<sub>1. Or use `{ echo '<DATA>'; cat file_name; echo '</DATA>'; } | xmlstarlet ...`  as Peter.O notes in the comment below</sub>

<sup>2. Using space as the delimiter does not align the columns properly</sup>

Comment: Instead of creaitng another file to accomodate the DATA tag, just pipe the extra tags, along with the *html output*, into `xmlstarlet`, eg.:   `{ echo '<DATA>'; cat html-file; echo '</DATA>'; } | xmlstarlet …` - where `cat html-file` may be a program vs. a file.

Comment: The output is not correct  –  `column -t`, by default, uses one-to-many spaces as its column separator – this results in the OS values being split into 2 columns.

Comment: @Peter.O Thanks for the great catch and answer below too!

Answer (score 2):

With your example and GNU sed:

```
sed -n 's/<[^>]*>//g;s/^ *//g;/./p' file | paste -d ";" - - - - | column -t -s ";"
```

Output:

```
WIN1  Windows 7  1.2.3.4      contoso.com
WIN2  Windows 8  10.20.30.40  contoso.com
```

I assume that your file does not contain a `;`. If you need a CSV remove `| column -t -s ";"`.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` script (plus `column` for output tabulation) will hande any sequence of placement of the *sub*-tags, and any whitespace separation of the tags - ie. it will handle the OP's sample input format, as well as the following sample which has *no whitespace* and *differently ordered* sub-tags:

```
    <HARDWARE><OS>Windows 7</OS><IP>1.2.3.4</IP><DOMAIN>contoso.com</DOMAIN><NAME>WIN1</NAME></HARDWARE><HARDWARE><NAME>WIN2</NAME><OS>Windows 8</OS><DOMAIN>contoso.com</DOMAIN><IP>10.20.30.40</IP></HARDWARE>
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="[[:space:]]*</?HARDWARE>[[:space:]]*"
            FS="[[:space:]]*<|</[^<>/]+>[[:space:]]*"
            tn=split( "NAME OS IP DOMAIN", tag_order, " " ) 
     } 
     $0 { delete tag
          for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) if($i) { n=index($i,">"); tag[substr($i,1,n-1)]=substr($i,n+1)  } 
          for( i=1;i<=tn;i++ ) printf "%s\t", tag[tag_order[i]]; print ""
     }' file | column -ts$'\t'
```

output:

```
WIN1  Windows 7  1.2.3.4      contoso.com
WIN2  Windows 8  10.20.30.40  contoso.com
```

Answer (score 0):

with `awk` - arbitrarily set each column to be 15 characters long, left-aligned and filled with spaces:

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS = "<[A-Za-z/]+>" } { if ( NR % 6 == 0 ) { printf"\n" } else if ( $2 != "" ) { printf"%-15s", $2 } }' file
```

Or as in the other answers in combination with `column`

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS = "<[A-Za-z/]+>" } { if ( NR % 6 == 0 ) { printf"\n" } else if ( $2 != "" ) { printf"%s ", $2 } }' file | column -t
```

Comment: *"arbitrarily set each colmn (width)"* means that you will arbitrarily get whacky output.

Comment: @Peter.O Agreed, but tabs wont help either due to the different lengths of the fields. I assume there is no other option than to use `column` when it should be sorted that nicely without a fixed column width, or is there?